# I'm about to leave FOR the concert or I'm about to leave TO the concert?

Tags: prepositions

I'm confused with the preposotions. Can you tell me which one is often used and which one is correct? Thank you.
here goes the sentence

> I'm about to leave **FOR** the concert

vs.

> I'm about to leave **TO** the  concert.

Answer (score 3):

When you are going from one place to another, the normal English and American usage is to say that:

> I am leaving for (the game) (school) (the city) (the concert) (Amsterdam) etc.

However, when 'leaving' is followed by 'to go' then 'for' is replaced by 'to', e.g.

> I am leaving to go to (the game) (school) (the city) (the concert) (Amsterdam) etc.

NOTE: I have heard that some people say 'I'm leaving to...' instead of 'I'm leaving for...', but I have never personally heard anyone say this.

When bequeathing an item, verbally or in a written will, leaving to can be used:

> I am leaving my Lego collection to my grandson.
>
> My house and furnishings, I leave to my son.

When delegating responsibility for someone else to do something, 'leaving...to' or 'leaving...for' can be used:

> I hate filing, I'll leave it to/for you.
>
> John skipped school again, I'll leave it to/for you to talk to him.

You will also commonly see 'leave' followed by the full infinitive form of a verb.

> You have my leave to carry on.
>
> I need to leave to catch my train.